# Fairy One Wing storybook from 1960s

Tags: identification-request, folk-tales

I’m trying to find a copy of a beautifully illustrated storybook I had a a child in the 1960s called Fairy One Wing, which I loved very much. This is the exact title. Does anyone have a copy or know the publisher?

Comment: Hi ,You have provided a specific title which is great . Even so as much additional information as possible not simply the title :  the book content and appearance of book itself : cover art , illustration , publsiher , dates if known  . As Sherlock Holmes was wont to say at the start when interviewing clients " Omit no detail however slight". This wiki is helpful : literature.stackexchange.com/tags/identification-request/info – 
schweppz

Comment: Asking whether people personally own copies is off-topic. Asking how to purchase/acquire a copy is also off-topic. Asking for the name of the publisher, however, is on-topic. Would you like to focus the question onto the publisher, then?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Literature Stack Exchange. Please take a look at the [guidance for identification requests](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/identification-request/info) and [edit your question](https://literature.stackexchange.com/posts/25944/edit) to include any additional information you can remember. E.g., what color and size was the book? How many pages? Was it a newly published book when you had it, or a book that had been published earlier? What was the story line? What werre the illustrations like? Such details can help us narrow down the book and identify it. Thanks!

Comment: Was it included in Mable Lucie Atwell book? I am also looking for a copy
Yvonne

Comment: Fairy One Wing sounds odd to my ear as a title...

Answer (score 3):

Could the story have been part of a book called *Fairyland Treasury, The One Winged Fairy and Other Tales*?

It has about five stories about fairies by different authors. Luisa Willoughby, Rene Cloke, Julie Cavalea. The book is blue with a little girl opening a chest on the front cover. The story about one wing features (among other insects) a lady bird family with a ladybird called Billy.